# How to catch JS/jquery click action in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggle

I use a language switcher on a php webpage (based on browser language on first load) but when the user changes the language it will not be remembered on reload (page has a `<FORM>` with `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`. The language switcher uses JS/jquery and doesn't reload the page. (works really beautifully)

Simplified HTML:

```
<button>
<span>Switch to English</span>
<span style="display: none">Seite auf deutsch</span>
</button>
```

JS:

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
  $( "span" ).toggle();
});
```

fiddle is a bit expanded but functionally the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/yello/k4p7r50t/

How can I catch the toggle state (js/browser) and move it over to php (server)? I think setting a cookie can do that, but I so far my tries to set the toggle state in a cookie failed. I did set a class for the non-show item in a test, but so far only failure.

Comment: Add some `data`-attribute to your button, change it and send to server via ajax.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? You've already found a way to catch the click, and setting a cookie might be possible and should work...

Comment: Show us how you tried to work with cookie that didn't work

Comment: Nico, I am playing around with cookie code I found and checked it with F12 `console.log`. It never worked. I am not sure about the `data` too, I just have only one button, that toggles.

Comment: I'm a bit busy right now but did a little change to be worked out later. I added a `id="test"` the the buttons `style="display: none"` option - and added a  `console.log(test);` to the jquery. In F12 console I can see no three states: `nothing' (first page load, first click) `display: none` (2nd click), `display: inline` (3rd click). After that `none` and `inline` will toggle. I will work on it later. But hints are always welcome. Here is the new fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/yello/xtp8dpzL/